# Execute Query After GOTO Syntax

Tags: sql-server, goto

I have a sample query, my problem is how to execute query after triggering `GOTO` syntax.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @TotalMaarks INT
SET @TotalMaarks = 49

IF @TotalMaarks >= 50
   GOTO Pass

IF @TotalMaarks < 50
   GOTO Fail

PRINT ' Congratulations '

Pass:
   PRINT ' Congratulations '
   PRINT ' You pass the Examination '
   RETURN

Fail:
   PRINT ' You Failed! '
   PRINT ' Better Luck Next Time '
   RETURN
GO
```

The result of that query will `GOTO Fail:`

> You Failed!
>
> Better Luck Next Time

But I want is after triggering `Fail:` it will also execute `PRINT 'Congratulations'`

Expected result:

> You Failed!
>
> Better Luck Next Time
>
> Congratulations

How can I return to `IF` to execute the other left queries?

Because after the `Fail` it will end.

Comment: Um - "fail" and "congratulations" just do **NOT** go together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid GOTO.  It used to be necessary for error handling before TRY/CATCH was added to TSQL, but I can't really think of a scenario where I would use it any more.  GOTO is discouraged in almost every language that has it, way back to the famous 1968 paper [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)

```
DECLARE @TotalMaarks INT
SET @TotalMaarks = 49

IF @TotalMaarks >= 50
BEGIN
   PRINT ' Congratulations '
   PRINT ' You pass the Examination '
END
ELSE IF @TotalMaarks < 50
BEGIN
   PRINT ' You Failed! '
   PRINT ' Better Luck Next Time '
END

PRINT ' Congratulations '

GO
```